# How to proxy all methods from a Python module to another?

Tags: python

I want to have in my application a common logging module that logs to a file. 
For example in my commonlog.py I can have something like this:

```
# Python logging module
import logging                                                   

logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

From the other modules in the application I want to import this module and be able to use it like if it was the Python logging module but without replicating all its functions, for example from module test.py:

```
import commonlog

commonlog.debug("debug message")
commonlog.info("info message")
commonlog.ANY_OTHER_METHOD_THAT_BELONGS_TO_LOGGING()
```

**How can I "proxy" in my commonlog all the methods from the logging module ?**

Doing:

```
commonlogging.logging.etc..
```

is not a valid solution because it's using the logging module directly.

Comment: from logging import debug as blablablalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had to "inherit" from a module before so I don't know it's naive to do a `from logging import *` at the top of `commonlogging`.  Here's code showing that it appears to work:

```
>>> with open('mylogging.py', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('''from logging import *
... my_customization = "it works"''')
...
>>> import mylogging
>>> print mylogging.my_customization
it works
>>> help(mylogging.log)
Help on function log in module logging:

log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)
    Log 'msg % args' with the integer severity 'level' on the root logger.
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about that, `from module import *` should do the trick, thanks!