# Extending Python Minidom

Tags: python, dom, minidom

There's a way to extends `minidom`?

I've tried this test with `ZipFile` and it works:

Having this code in file `testzip.py`:

```
import zipfile

class zip( zipfile.ZipFile ):
   def test( self ):
      print( 'test' )
```

this example code works fine:

```
import sys
import testzip

zip = testzip.zip( sys.argv[1], 'r' )
zip.test()
```

I have tried in many ways to do the same with minidom, but without results.

Basically, I would like a class having minidom methods and user-defined methods:

```
import myminidom

doc = myminidom.parseString( txt )
doc.getElementsByTagName("meta")
doc.customMethod1( customArg1 )
```

There's a way to obtains this, or is it impossible?
I've tried with `class myminidom( minidom )` and I understand it's not possible because I can't extends an object, i've tried with `class myminidom( minidom.parseStr )`, but i got a `TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minidom is not a  class. its a module, you cannot inheret modules.
You can make a proxy if you really want to

see:
[How to proxy all methods from a Python module to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941135/how-to-proxy-all-methods-from-a-python-module-to-another)

Comment: Many Thanks. You write "if you really want" because is deprecated or a bad practice?

Comment: Its a code smell I guess, But hey! python is for adults :)